# Understanding Observables, Promises, this and a passing data around in Angular, Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Trying to understand why I am getting

> "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.dealership is undefined"

from

authentication.service.ts

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<UserModel>;
  public currentUser: Observable<UserModel>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<UserModel>(
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authenticatedUser'))
    );
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public get currentUserValue(): UserModel {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
  }

  login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http
      .post<any>(`${environment.nodeUrl}/api/login`, { username, password })
      .pipe(
        map(user => {
          // store user details and basic auth credentials in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
          user.authdata = window.btoa(username + ':' + password);
          localStorage.setItem('authenticatedUser', user);
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', user['data'][0]['username']);
          localStorage.setItem('currentDealer', user['data'][0]['username'] );
          localStorage.setItem('currentDealerID', user['data'][0]['dealerid'] );
          localStorage.setItem('sites', user['data'][0]['siteids'].split('|') );
          localStorage.setItem('marquees', user['data'][0]['marqueeids'].split('|') );
          localStorage.setItem('email', user['data'][0]['email'] );
          localStorage.setItem('firstName', user['data'][0]['firstname']);
          localStorage.setItem('lastName', user['data'][0]['lastname']);
          this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
          return user;
        })
      );
  }
```

DealerSiteComponent

```
export class DealerSiteComponent {
  private dealership: {dealerName: string, dealerId: string};
  dealershipName: string;
  dealershipId: number;
  selectedSite: string;
  marques: {marqueId: number, marqueName: string}[] = [];
  sites: {siteId: number, siteName: string}[] = [];


  constructor(
    /// private dataService: AggregateService
    private authService: AuthenticationService
  ) {
      const userDetails = authService.currentUserValue;
      console.log(userDetails);
      this.dealership.dealerName = localStorage.getItem('currentDealer');
      this.dealership.dealerId = localStorage.getItem('currentDealerID');
      this.dealershipName = localStorage.getItem('currentDealerI
}
```

Very sure I don't understand Observables too well.

How can learn understand this stuff better?

Thanks

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Structurally, I don't think there is anything wrong with your `authentication.service.ts`.

The only issue I see is what you have written in `DealerSiteComponent`, and this is the reason why it returns the above error you have stated:

`dealership` is not assigned a value, yet you are trying to reference its properties and assign them a value. In addition, you will need to subscribe to the service's `login` method in order to 
return the observables, which will trigger the pipeline to populate the `currentUserSubject` with the `user` response returned by the http request in the `login` method. And last but not least, you should handle the logic written in the constructor in the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook instead.

```
interface Dealership {
  dealerName?: string;
  dealerId?: string;
}

export class DealerSiteComponent implements OnInit {
  private dealership: Dealership = {
    dealerName: undefined,
    undefined,
  }
  // do the rest

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.login.subscribe(() => {
      const userDetails = this.authService.currentUserValue;
      console.log(userDetails);
      this.dealership.dealerName = localStorage.getItem('currentDealer');
       this.dealership.dealerId = localStorage.getItem('currentDealerID');
       // handle rest
    });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the underlying `Subject` from your service to your component. And in your component you need to `subscribe` to the exposed `Subject` to get the actual value.

And a suggestion to your code would be not to put too much code in the constructor. Instead, you might wanna do it in `ngOnInit`.